# Can't convert from int to "classname"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While building a ASP.NET-MVC website I was trying to implement a **EDIT** page on my website, but I'm having some difficulties, particulary in my Controller. The error is in this class, pointing to the ID:

```
 public IActionResult Edit(int ID = 0)
            {
                GestaoAlertas _teste = addresses.Contains(ID);
                return View(_teste);
            }
```

And the **error** says:

> It is not possible to convert from int to "hdsportal.GestaoAlertas"

**Controller:**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        List<GestaoAlertas> addresses = new List<GestaoAlertas>();

        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            con.ConnectionString = "secret";
        }

        public IActionResult Gestao_Alertas()
        {
            FetchData();
            return View(addresses);
        }

        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            FetchData();
            return View(addresses);
        }

        public IActionResult Edit(int ID = 0)
        {
            GestaoAlertas _teste = addresses.Contains(ID);
            return View(_teste);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacidade()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Gestao_Utilizadores()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contatos()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult QuemSomos()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private void FetchData()
        {
                if (addresses.Count > 0)
                {

                    addresses.Clear();
                }
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    com.Connection = con;
                    com.CommandText = "SELECT [ID], [SYSTEM_NAME], [SYSTEM_STATUS], [SYSTEM_SHORTMSG] FROM [CORE_SYS_STATUS]";
                    dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        addresses.Add(new GestaoAlertas()
                        {
                            ID = (int)dr["ID"]
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_NAME = dr["SYSTEM_NAME"].ToString()
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_STATUS = dr["SYSTEM_STATUS"].ToString()
                        ,
                            SYSTEM_SHORTMSG = dr["SYSTEM_SHORTMSG"].ToString()

                        });
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   throw ex;
                }
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class GestaoAlertas
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string SYSTEM_NAME { get; set; }
        public string SYSTEM_STATUS { get; set; }
        public string SYSTEM_SHORTMSG { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue & Concern

According to [`List<T>.Contains(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8), you need parse `T` object which is `GestaoAlertas` object to your `addresses` (`List<GestaoAlertas>` type).

Hence,  you get the error below as it is an unmatched type with `int`

> It is not possible to convert from int to "hdsportal.GestaoAlertas"

for this line:

```cs
GestaoAlertas _teste = addresses.Contains(ID);
```

**And `List<T>.Contains(T)` returns the boolean result.**

```cs
public bool Contains (T item);
```

> Determines whether an element is in the List.

---

### Solution(s)

**Assumptions:**

1. `addresses` contain `GestaoAlertas` records

You can get `GestaoAlertas` element from `addresses` by `ID` with either of these LINQ methods:

**Pre-requisite:**

Import `System.Linq` namespace.

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

**Solution 1: [Enumerable.SingleOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.8)**

> Returns a single, specific element of a sequence, or a default value if that element is not found.

**Note: It will throw `InvalidOperationException` if input sequence contains more than one element. Good to be use for unique identifier such as ID.**

```cs
GestaoAlertas _teste = addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID);
```

---

**Solution 2: [Enumerable.Single](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8)**

> Returns a single, specific element of a sequence.

**Note: It will throw `ArgumentNullException` if it returns `null`.**

```cs
GestaoAlertas _teste = addresses.Single(x => x.ID == ID);
```

---

**Solution 3: [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)**

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is found.

```cs
GestaoAlertas _teste = addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID);
```

---

**Solution 4: [Enumerable.First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8)**

> Returns the first element of a sequence.

**Note: It will throw `ArgumentNullException` if it returns `null`.**

```cs
GestaoAlertas _teste = addresses.First(x => x.ID == ID);
```

Comment: Very well constructed solution, it worked 100%, thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome, good to see that you get your answer.